# Can we purchase AppleCare in India for MacBook Air purchased from USA?

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

I am from India, and I have come to US for work. Today I am going to purchase a MacBook Air 256GB 13" with Retina display. Due to budget restrictions, I will not be able to purchase AppleCare along with it.

I want to know the following:

1. Once I purchase the laptop from US and come back to India, will I be able to purchase AppleCare for this laptop here in India?
2. If yes, will there be any restrictions on the AppleCare?
3. If no, what can I do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple recommends you to purchase an AppleCare protection plan in your country of residence, implying the country where you'll be seeking repair services.

- [Support - AppleCare - FAQ - Apple (IN)](https://www.apple.com/in/support/products/faqs.html)

> #### Where can I purchase the AppleCare Protection Plan?
>
> The AppleCare Protection Plan is available at the [Apple Online Store](http://store.apple.com/in) and many [Apple-authorised resellers and wireless service providers](https://www.apple.com/id/buy/).

To answer your questions:

> 1. Once I purchase the laptop from US and come back to India, will I be able to purchase AppleCare for this laptop here in India?

Yes.

> 2. If yes, will there be any restrictions on the AppleCare?

No.

**P.S.**: The answers are based on information provided by Apple and from personal experiences.

Comment: The link does not work anymore @Nimesh

Comment: @ShreyanMehta Thank you. I have updated the answer to point to the new link. Apple has launched the online store in India after the answer was originally written and the information has been updated in the wake of same.